# New Zealand precise duration of the "visa waiver visitor visa"

Tags: visas, new-zealand

Everywhere i checked, the duration of this visa is 3 months.

But what is 3 months? Is it from, for example, 3 january to 3 april? Or is there a duration in days, like 90ish days?

I need this information for booking plane tickets.

Thanks

Comment: Immigration officers tend to get a little jumpy when people try to use the maximum extent of visa-free entry. It might also get you into trouble if, for example, you miss your flight home. Given that, it would probably be a good idea to stay a little less than three months, which means you don't need to know exactly what "three months" means anyway.

Comment: David Richerby is right.  I once landed at AKL at about 4am and the entry stamp hadn't been updated from the night before, so I was stamped in on the wrong date.  Didn't matter to me - I was going to be long gone by the time it expired - but it's the sort of error that'll be a real nuisance to fix and might make all the difference if you're aiming to use your entire allocation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Three months" means three calendar months, as per section 29 of the [Interpretation Act 1999](http://www.legislation.govt.nz/act/public/1999/0085/latest/DLM31803.html):

> **month** means a calendar month

How many days the three months represent (89 to 92 days) will depend on the number of days the actual months concerned have.